# Can't create Google Charts when importing datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization

I am trying to create a line chart of changes in prices every minute.  I need to be able to pull the data from my site.  I can't get the chart to load if I use datetime for the x axis.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "sampleData.json",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 480});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can create a chart using the following for sampleData.json:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"X","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Line 1","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Line 2","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"5","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":5,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

But when I try to change x to a datetime, it won't load.

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"X","pattern":"","type":"datetime"},
        {"id":"","label":"Line 1","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Line 2","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":new Date(2017,0,1,12,1),"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":new Date(2017,0,1,12,2),"f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":new Date(2017,0,1,12,3),"f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":new Date(2017,0,1,12,4),"f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":new Date(2017,0,1,12,5),"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":5,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the new keyword when working with JSON.

From google charts:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes

"When serializing data using the JavaScript DataTable object literal notation to build your DataTable, the new Date() constructor cannot be used. Instead, Google Charts provides a Date string representation that allows your date or datetime to be serialized and parsed properly when creating a DataTable. This Date string format simply drops the new keyword and wraps the remaining expression in quotation marks:

"Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds)"

Comment: I cannot for the life of me get this to work. `Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value Date(2000, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0) does not match type datetime in column index 0`